# Using Office 2007 PIAs with Excel 2002 (Primary Interop Assembly)

Tags: excel, office-interop, office-pia

Is this possible?

My app references Excel 2007 Primary Interop Assemblies. Can I install these on a PC which has only Excel 2002 (XP) installed?

Or do I need the Office XP PIAs?

In that case, do I need to modify my program to reference the old PIAs?

Answer (score 1):

Just did a quick search and this link may help: [Achieving Backward Compatibility with .NET Interop: Excel as Case Study](http://devcity.net/printarticle.aspx?articleid=163)

The short answer seems to be `Interops` are not forward compatible, i.e. they will not work with lower versioned assemblies in deployed environment than targeted originally. In order to target lower version you should reference the lower version assemblies explicitly.